# Is there a sure option to fixed-position headers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, accessibility

As a user with a disability (and legacy Windows user) I use the mouse only when absolutely necessary.

It's almost humorous that web developers forget our reliance on the keyboard.

Enter the popular (darn you Bootstrap!) fixed-position header/navbar.

Visit a website with this feature, press `spacebar` to scroll down and you'll likely be unable to read the top few lines.

Bootstrap's solution is a start. They recommend a `top-margin` to accommodate the fixed bar. This doesn't work on scrolling. Content is still obscured.

Anyone have some solutions or best practices?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking here. Whether or not a fixed header obscures content – how is that depending on what kind of input device (mouse/keyboard) you use to trigger scrolling …?

Comment: @CBroe it just does. Mouse scrolling moves slowly down, but pressing spacebar advances the entire window up with the bottom line advanced across top. For some it is the most efficient browsing method.

Comment: A down vote?! This is a real-world design issue. Sheesh!

Comment: Well, then I guess you have to use cursor keys to scroll instead. (Unless your browser lets you configure how far down pressing space bar scrolls, some do.)

Comment: I agree, a downvote on a legitimate accessibility question make no sense. I verified what you are referring to and you are correct although they use padding on the body, not margin. After playing with this for a few I don't see an easy solution because when hitting the spacebar, the browser measures the total page size and the moves the page the equivalent amount. Unfortunately, this includes the size of the fixed navbar which is why it scrolls the correct length PLUS the size of the navbar. I'm unaware of a fix because this is an action of the browser, not the webpage itself.

Comment: Are you looking for solutions that the web site should implement? If so, please provide example code demonstrating the issue. Or are you looking for some kind of user-implemented solution?

Comment: It sounds like his problem is with the Bootstrap framework itself that every website uses, am I right?
Upvoted, just because I don't understand why this question deserves a downvote.

Comment: @CraigBrett I've left this AWOL and am surprised there's no real action from the Bootstrap community to fix this and pretty miffed at the down votes and disregard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple solution: Put all of the non-header contents into a containing element. Give the header `position: fixed;` and `top: 0;`. Then give the container `position: relative;` and a `margin-top` roughly equal to the height of the header.  Example:

Style:

```
h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5rem;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #bada55;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10em;
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Morbi ornare sagittis enim a pulvinar.</li>
    <li>Aenean a elit tempor, tempor dui eu, blandit est.</li>
    <li>Sed id dui condimentum, posuere neque quis, laoreet diam.</li>
   ...
  </ol>
</div>
```

Working demo: http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/wAzbi